# Why Account.LastActivityDate is not visible on any of SF UI?

Tags: formula-field, account, standard-objects

While solving one of the trailhead challenge I came accross Account.LastActivityDate field. I was not able to view this field in Account field list and had to google about it.

I was able to solve the problem and understood the [purpose](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=What-is-the-difference-between-Last-Activity-and-Last-Modified-1327108315155&language=en_US) of this field.

One thing I did not understand is why do they have field and then keep it hidden on all SF UI?

It can be accessed via API or SOQL.

Can any one provide more details about it?

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect it is to avoid confusion with the last updated field on Salesforce standard UI fields.

Comment: I don't think so. Why? because it is not visible on Setup->Account->Fields as well.

Comment: And there is significant difference between these two.  Check the link is question.

Answer (score 2):

Not every field needs to be visible to every user (in fact, less is often better). Account has an Activities Related List. If one looks at that related list, it's often immediately obvious what the LastActivityDate is.

From the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf):

> **LastActivityDate**
>
> **Type**
>
> string
>
> **Properties**
>
> Filter, Group, Nillable, Sort
>
> **Description**
>
> Value is one of the following, whichever is the most recent:
>
> • Due date of the most recent event logged against the record.
>
> • Due date of the most recently closed task associated with the record.

**Edit**

I can't give you a definitive answer as to why the field isn't available for selection for display from Setup -> Account -> Field. The primary reason I can think of would be that the field is actually related to Activities (Tasks & Events). Without a Task or Event to reference, it's meaningless and of no value or use. From a practical standpoint, the field is probably best used in the context of reports.

That having being said, it somehow sticks in my mind that the field may be indexed (uncertain of that's true and would want to verify it before stating it as a fact). If so, I'd expect it's real purpose to be that of a "helper" which is used to speed up queries conducted in the background by Salesforce as an aid in finding related records from Activities.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am fine with hiding it from Account Detail Screen but why from setup -> Account -> field list. At least admin should be able to view it so that he/she can use it appropriately. Otherwise only option is left is to use workbench like tool.